# jquery activation all hover class

Tags: jquery

I would like my different classes that have class:hover, activates all at the same time the one of them is hover.

For example I have a lot of div who change bg-image when I hover and for the responsive design this will probably be hard to change the style in the jquery code.

For the moment I have something like that with much more classes but basically it's that :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box0,.box1').hover(
    function() {
      $('.box0,.box1').toggleClass("hover");
    })
});
```

```css
html {}

body {
  background: darkgray;
}

.box0 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  background-image: url(res/arrow-black.png);
}

.box0:hover {
  background-image: url(res/arrow-green.png);
  background-color: royalblue;
}

.box1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

.box1:hover {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="box0"></div>
<div class="box1"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want. but as per my understanding.. you want to active hover all elements with same class if you hover over one of them ...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.element').mouseover(
    function() {
      $('.element').addClass("active");
    });
   
$('.element').mouseout(
    function() {
      $('.element').removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

```css
html {}

body {
  background: darkgray;
}

.box0 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  background-image: url(res/arrow-black.png);
}

.box0.active {
  background-image: url(res/arrow-green.png);
  background-color: royalblue;
}

.box1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

.box1.active {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="element box0"></div>
<div class="element box1"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you could create a hover event then loop through the elements to toggle the `hover` class.

```js
$('div[class^=box]').hover(function() {
  $('div[class^=box]').each(function(i) {
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: darkgray;
}

.box0 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  background-image: url(res/arrow-black.png);
}

.box0.hover {
  background-image: url(res/arrow-green.png);
  background-color: royalblue;
}

.box1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

.box1.hover {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

.box2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.box2.hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

.box3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.box3.hover {
  background-color: black;
}

.box4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: purple;
}

.box4.hover {
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box0"></div>
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box3"></div>
<div class="box4"></div>
```

Comment: Yes exactly ! But I think I do not understand exactly how you call the classes with: 'div[class^=box]' Is it all classes that contain box ?

Comment: Yes, any `<div>` with class `box*` will be selected. Saves you from having to specify them individually.

Comment: @Jules - Also, I don't know if there's a specific reason you are using absolute positioning. But if you wrapped all those `<div>`s in a parent with `display: flex;` you can get the same layout with much less CSS.

Comment: Good to know ;) And what do I do if I have to add one that is not named like that?

Comment: You would just need to add it manually, like so `'div[class^=box], .diffClass'`.